# Query that gives me back musics with more relevancy

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, youtube-api

I have a query JS that gives me back musics when I search for a artist name, can someone please tell me how can I make appear first the musics with more relevancy, for example the more famous musics first. I'm using youtube api.

```js
$("#submeter").click(function() {
      if ($("#artist").val() != "") {

        query = $("#artist").val()

        let url = "http://musicbrainz.org/ws/2/artist/?query=artist:" + query + "&fmt=json";
        url = encodeURI(url);

        $.get(url, function(response, status) {
              if (status == 'success') {
                //alert(response.works)
                //alert(query);
                $(".form").hide();
                $(".div-pesquisa").show();
                $(".div-pesquisa h3").html("You searched for \" " + $("#artist").val() + " \" ");

                url = "http://musicbrainz.org/ws/2/artist/" + response.artists[0].id + "?inc=releases&fmt=json";
                url = encodeURI(url);
                //alert(url);
                $.get(url, function(response, status) {
                      if (status == 'success') {
                        url = "http://musicbrainz.org/ws/2/release/" + response.releases[0].id + "?inc=recordings&fmt=json";
                        url = encodeURI(url);
                        $.get(url, function(response, status) {
                          if (status == 'success') {
                            //for (var i = -1; i < 3 ; i++){


                            url = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?q=" + query + " " + response.media[0].tracks[0].title + "&maxResults=1&part=snippet&key=" + youtubeAPIKey;
                            url = encodeURI(url);
                            //alert(url);
                            //alert(i);
                            $.get(url, function(response, status) {
                              if (status == 'success') {
                                //$("#topmusic1 figure img").attr("src", response.items[0].snippet.thumbnails.high.url).css("height", "240px").css("width", "100%");
                                $("#topmusic1 figure div h6").html(response.items[0].snippet.title);
                                $("#topmusic1 figure i").click(function() {
                                  $(".div-pesquisa").hide();
                                  $(".player").show();
                                  $(".player iframe").attr('src', "https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + response.items[0].id.videoId).css("border", "0").css("width", "100%").css("height", "100%");
                                });
                              }
                            });


                            url = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?q=" + query + " " + response.media[0].tracks[1].title + "&maxResults=1&part=snippet&key=" + youtubeAPIKey;
                            url = encodeURI(url);
                            //alert(url);
                            //alert(i);
                            $.get(url, function(response, status) {
                              if (status == 'success') {
                                // $("#topmusic2 figure img").attr("src", response.items[0].snippet.thumbnails.high.url).css("height", "240px").css("width", "100%");
                                $("#topmusic2 figure div h6").html(response.items[0].snippet.title);
                                $("#topmusic2 figure i").click(function() {
                                  $(".div-pesquisa").hide();
                                  $(".player").show();
                                  $(".player iframe").attr('src', "https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + response.items[0].id.videoId).css("border", "0").css("width", "100%").css("height", "100%");
                                });
                              }
                            });


                            url = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?q=" + query + " " + response.media[0].tracks[2].title + "&maxResults=1&part=snippet&key=" + youtubeAPIKey;
                            url = encodeURI(url);
                            //alert(url);
                            //alert(i);
                            $.get(url, function(response, status) {
                              if (status == 'success') {
                                // $("#topmusic3 figure img").attr("src", response.items[0].snippet.thumbnails.high.url).css("height", "240px").css("width", "100%");
                                $("#topmusic3 figure div h6").html(response.items[0].snippet.title);
                                $("#topmusic3 figure i").click(function() {
                                  $(".div-pesquisa").hide();
                                  $(".player").show();
                                  $(".player iframe").attr('src', "https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + response.items[0].id.videoId).css("border", "0").css("width", "100%").css("height", "100%");
                                });
                              }
                            });

                            //}
                          }
                        });
```

Comment: Please update the snippet I made with HTML and enough script to make a [mcve]

Comment: But you didn't. Please add HTML and CSS to show a working example and describe how to reproduce the issue